# How to add special character in sql query in java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, full-text-search

I have sql query using full text search. Code is developed using Spring framework and my query is executing using SimpleJDBC template. Can anyone please tell me how to append "+" in the full text query in java.

Below is my sql query:

```
SELECT match(`title`,`description`,`location`) against (+:keyword  +:location IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) FROM  job
```

"keyword" and "location" will be passed as parameters to this query. I am using "AND" operation to filter results based on matching of two parameters. How to add "+" in the sql query.

Comment: First, are you concatenating this as a string, or are you passing in the arguments using a PreparedStatement?  You should not be concatenating strings for SQL.  JDBC handles escaping stuff for you.  If this doesn't apply, then I would like to see some Java code so I can better assist you.

Comment: I am concating String using "+". It is the AND operator in full text search. I want to pass parameter including "+" in the query. I tried '+':keyword '+':location. But it is not working as expected

Comment: Can you show me your Java code?  It is HIGHLY recommended not to use concatenation to set parameters on a SQL statement.  This is how your code becomes susceptible to SQL injection attacks.